# Good analytic spaces over a field into locally ringed spaces is fully faithful

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, berkovich-geometry

Let $k$ be a field which is complete with respect to a non-trivial non-archimedean rank-1 valuation, and let $X$ be scheme which is locally of finite type over $k$. In section of 3.5 of [Berkovich's book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Spectral_Theory_and_Analytic_Geometry_Ov.html?id=6x5PIl2-DkkC), he defines the analytification of $X$ to be the closed $k$-analytic space $X^{\textrm{an}}$ representing the following functor: let $\textrm{An}_k$ be the category of good analytic spaces over $k$, and let $F_X \colon \textrm{An}_k \to (\textrm{Sets})$ be the functor which sends a good analytic space $Z$ over $k$ to the set of morphisms $Z \to X$ of locally $k$-ringed spaces.

In order for Berkovich's proof to work, it seems that we need the functor from $\textrm{An}_k$ to the category of locally ringed spaces to be fully faithful; that is, every morphism of locally ringed spaces between two good analytic spaces must in fact be a morphism of analytic spaces over $k$. This fact is stated without proof on page 16 of Berkovich's [Trieste notes](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vova/Trieste_2009.pdf), but how could one prove this?

However, there is also Remark 2.1.13 of Berkovich's book, which gives an example of a morphism (of locally ringed spaces) between $k$-affinoid spaces which is not a morphism of $k$-affinoid spaces. As $k$-affinoid spaces are examples of good analytic spaces, this seems to contradict the above assertion of fully faithfulness (granted, this particular example is over a trivially-valued field). This issue also does not seem to be addressed in Berkovich's [IHES paper](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vova/IHES_1993_78_etale.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would like to say that I do not understand why you need the full faithfullness of the analytification functor. It seems to me that the main point is to prove that giving a morphism from an analytic space $X$ to the affine analytic space of dimension $n$ is equivalent to giving $n$ global section of $X$.

Second, as you rightly say, the functor is not fully faithful over trivially valued fields nor for non-strict spaces (see Remark 2.1.13 of Berkovich's book), so let us assume that the valuation is non-trivial and that the spaces are strict. We can reduce to the case of a morphism between strictly $k$-affinoid spaces, say $f : X \to Y$. By taking global sections, you find an induced morphism between affinoid algebras $A_Y \to A_X$ and [BGR, Theorem 6.3.1/1] tells you that such a morphism is always continuous. Arguing as for schemes, you then prove that the induced morphism $X = \mathcal{M}(A_X) \to \mathcal{M}(A_Y) = Y$ coincides with $f$ for rigid points. By density of rigid points (which holds over a non-trivially valued field), it coincides with $f$ everywhere.

Comment: I agree that one does not need the fully faithfullness of the analytification functor, but rather of the natural functor from good analytic spaces over $k$ into locally ringed spaces. The reason I think this is needed is exactly for what you pointed out: if $Z \in \textrm{An}_k$ is good, then $\Gamma(Z, \mathcal{O}_Z) \simeq \textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{An}_k}(Z,\mathbf{A}^1)$ but you need that $\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ is also isomorphic to the morphisms  $Z \to \mathbf{A}^1$ of locally ringed spaces. This would follow from the fully faithfulness.

Comment: OK, sorry, I did not comment on that point. You should find what you need here (for instance): http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I1.

Comment: Also, it seems that $A_Y \to A_X$ is just homomorphism between two $k$-affinoid algebras; in order for it to be continuous, we would need that they are strictly $k$-affinoid, would we not? Or can one initially reduce to the strictly $k$-affinoid case somehow?

Comment: Yes, I totally overlooked that point. I think you are right and that Remark 2.1.13 of Berkovich's book shows that this is not always the case. Note that for the second example, you do not need $k$ to be trivially valued. I will edit my answer.

Comment: So are you saying that Fact 3.2.10(i) of Berkovich's [Trieste notes](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/244409/good-analytic-spaces-over-a-field-into-locally-ringed-spaces-is-fully-faithful) is wrong? (That is, it should be replaced with a functor from the category of good _strictly_ $k$-analytic spaces.) For my question about analytification, the current answer is fine though, since analytifications are strictly $k$-analytic.

Comment: I wanted to write Remark 2.1.13 (and ended up typing something completely unrelated for some reason). I agree that this is difficult to imagine that Berkovich overlooked this point but I see nothing wrong with the counter-example (that he provided himself). I suggest that you write him an email if you are still bothered.